# jQuery datepicker not showing on admin menu

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, admin-menu, jquery-ui, datepicker

Nothing happens when I select the datepicker field.

This is the code for the field:

```
<input id="sticky_date" name="sticky_date" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text">
```

The javascript

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:-10"
  });
});
```

The include code

```
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_datepicker');
function admin_datepicker() {
  wp_register_script(
    'pub-datepicker',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/js/datepicker.js',
    array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ),
    false,
    true
  );
  wp_enqueue_script('pub-datepicker');
}
```

I'm not really sure if I'm missing something, there's no error on the js console, nothing happens

Comment: Check https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ that your scripts are being added in php hooks, your page source that they are being rendered and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/performance-analyser/djgfmlohefpomchfabngccpbaflcahjf to see when it happens.

Comment: All files are shown as 200 OK in Net tab of Firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
My input field was declared like this:

`<input id="sticky_date" name="sticky_date" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text">`

It turns out that the `hasDatepicker` is assigned by the js when the date picker popup is shown, so when I clicked it nothing happened because it basically "thought" that the popup had been shown already. I simply changed it to:

`<input id="sticky_date" name="sticky_date" class="datepicker" type="text">`

Answer (score 0):

Use `admin_enqueue_scripts` action instead of `admin_head`. Then see network tab in dev tools that datepicker scripts are included.

You need the include the jQuery UI CSS also, it is not included in WP core.

Comment: Added the CSS and changed from admin_head to admin_enqueue_scripts, all files are shown as 200 OK in network tab

Comment: What happens when you run `jQuery( '.datepicker' ).datepicker();` in a console? Check that your form input is in that page

Comment: This was printed: `Object { 0: <input#pub_sticky_date.datepicker.hasDatepicker>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → admin.php, selector: ".datepicker" }`

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct, you might have included and its execured before the element(`.datepicker`) is present.
Please use `jQuery( document ).ready(function()` function

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:-10"
  });
});
```

Try the above and let us know if you see any error in console.

Comment: Still nothing. Not even an error

Comment: `jQuery(function () { } );` is equivalent to `jQuery( document ).ready(function() { } );`